# max and min of f(x,y,z)=z on V

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the max and min of the function $f(x,y,z)=z$ on V=$\{(x,y,z): z^3+y^2+xz+z+x^2=0\}$

I found with Lagrange multiplicators that (0,0,0) is the only stationary point.

How can I say if is a max or min?

Comment: i think we get $$-\infty\le z\le0$$ on $V$

Comment: so (0,0,0) is a max?

Comment: For local constrained min/max you can also use an augmented hessian matrix that includes the derivatives of the restrictions and analyse the sign of its principal minors.